# Скрипт назад с обновлением страницы

Tags: javascript, php

помогите, мне необходимо чтобы выполнялся скрипты перехода на предыдущую страницу, уже обновленную, через 3 секунды

```
setTimeout(function(){
          history.go(-1);
          location.reload();
        }, 3 * 1000);
```

Такого рода код перенаправляет страницу назад, но она старая, нужна обновленная

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается всё было просто

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href=document.referrer;
}, 3 * 1000);
```